# Does Chapel have something similar to a Python context manager?

Tags: chapel

In Python, you can use context managers to allocate and release resources within a block of code, such as opening and closing a file handle within the scope of a `with` block in this example:

```
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Can Chapel do this!?')
```

Does a similar feature exist in Chapel? If so, how would you translate the above code example to Chapel?

Comment: Maybe I miss some key, unsaid, point here, yet - why would a "mimicking" a concurrency-preventing Python, where GIL-lock avoids any benefits from even a just-[CONCURRENT] processing co-existence, by "mirroring" a syntax sugar constructors (for scope-limitations), ever help to improve Chapel in the fields of un-paralleled True-[PARALLEL] NUMA-infrastructure hardware mapped HPC processing and a **programming**-productivity ( hard to see in any other HPC-domain stack of programming languages and OpenMP+MPI+slurm tools from even seasoned HPC-professionals )? Could you add some such reason for it?

Comment: Even in the largest parallel programs, there are large chunks of serial code where traditional non-HPC language constructs can be a productivity boon to programmers.  For example, rather than having to explicitly have pairs of start/stop calls to timers, communication diagnostic routines, etc., context managers can serve as an attractive way to govern such enter/exit pairs cleanly.  We have also been looking at them as a tool to perform otherwise type-unsafe operations such as reallocating arrays whose elements' types have no default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapel introduced context manager support in Chapel 1.25 via the [`manage` statement](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.25/technotes/manage.html).

Here is a similar example from above. Note that builtin types do not yet include the `enterThis()` and `leaveThis()` methods necessary for context management to work. Therefore, we need to define those methods before using the manage statement in Chapel 1.25. This should not be necessary in future versions.

```
use IO;

// This should be part of standard library eventually
proc file.enterThis() ref { return this; }
proc file.leaveThis(in err: owned Error?) { this.close(); }


manage open('some_file.txt', iomode.cw) as f {
  var w = f.writer();
  w.write('yes');
}
```